# Xamarin forms crashed android project, when i use object property (get-set)

Tags: xamarin, properties

I ran into a problem while creating a project. If I use properties (get;set;), the android application crashes at the point of assigning a value to the property.

For example: I created a clean xamarin project to remove the influence of my code.

Property in my class:

```
 public class Item
    {
     public string Id
            {
                get { return Id; }
                set { Id = value; }
            }
    }
```

Property use:

```
 public AboutPage()
        {
            Item gg = new Item();
            gg.Id = "test";
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

App crashes at line:

```
set { Id = value; }
```

Error not show.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5WiH.png)

Help. This is the first time I've seen this. I have downgraded the platform. Used clean projects. What am I doing wrong?

UPD: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SrCvj1E58lpXDAwQ85Z89U4G6lp_b40M/view?usp=sharing) to my solution

Comment: Hello @Adventure, would you like to share the versions of Xamarin you use?

Comment: I use Xamarin Forms version 5.0.0.2012. The versions are recent and the project in the studio is clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to change the property like below:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

}
```

or

```
public class Item
{
    private string id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
}
```

when you impement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`  interface:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how it works. But this is not an option. I came across this issue when I was implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: @AdventureMania You could check above.

Comment: Thank you. I allowed reference by property name. This is my mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
public string Id
{
    get { return Id; }
    set { Id = value; }
}
```

You are essentially creating an infinite loop. This is why your App crashes. You are infinitely calling the setter.

Instead you would either make it an auto property:

```
public string Id { get; set; }
```

or add a backing field for the property:

```
private string _id;
public string Id
{
   get => _id;
   set => _id = value;
}
```